# making a class behave like a bunch of keyword arguments in python

Tags: python

So I have a class that will have a lot of attributes. Is there a way to make this class behave in a way that I can pass it as a **kwarg to a function?

```
class Foo ( object ) :
    def __init__( self ) :
         self.a = 'a'
         self.b = 'b'

foo = Foo()
somefunc(**foo)
```

I cannot find the right operator to overload.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

`**kwargs` expects a dictionary; the easiest way to make your class support `dict` operations (*ed:* apart from directly inheriting from `dict`, which also works) is to inherit from the [`collections.MutableMapping`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html) mixin, which will need you to define `__setitem__`, `__getitem__` and `__delitem__` and give you the rest of the `dict` interface for free.

You can keep an internal `dict` of attributes, pass those three functions through to it, and additionally implement `__setattr__` and `__getattr__` to support attribute-style access. Here's a [recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/389916/) that does something like what you're looking for - you need to be careful about messing with those two.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is [`vars`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#vars).

```
>>> def somefunc(**kwargs):
...     from pprint import pprint
...     pprint(kwargs)
...
>>> somefunc(**vars(foo))
{'a': 'a', 'b': 'b'}
```

No need to overload anything this way. `vars` is a builtin.